# Need to return opponents score as an alias of opponent rather than team by team

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query that displays teams scores for and against.  BUt I what it to display in a table so the Opponents scores area displayed by a alias of 'Opponent'.

I cant work it out using mysqi and someone suggested I need to create a function to pass the result.  I have no experience in writing functions and I've tried researching to find out how to, but with no luck.

My query

```
SELECT CONCAT(RoundNo, ',',Season) AS Game, Team, Total 
FROM MatchDetails  
WHERE Team = 'Team A' 
AND Season = 2015 
UNION
SELECT CONCAT(RoundNo, ',',Season) AS Game, Opponent, OTotal 
FROM MatchDetails  
WHERE Team = 'Team A'
AND Season = 2015
```

My current result set

```
Game| Team  | Total
1 |Team A   | 125
2 |Team A   | 80
3 |Team A   | 78
4 |Team A   | 89
5 |Team A   | 102
1 |Team B   | 100
2 |Team C   | 79
3 |Team D   | 85
4 |Team E   | 87
5 |Team F   | 45
```

My desired result set

```
Game| Team  | Total
1 |Team A   | 125
2 |Team A   | 80
3 |Team A   | 78
4 |Team A   | 89
5 |Team A   | 102
1 |Opponent | 100
2 |Opponent | 79
3 |Opponent | 85
4 |Opponent | 87
5 |Opponent | 45
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT CONCAT(RoundNo, ',', Season) AS Game, Team, Total 
FROM MatchDetails  
WHERE Team = 'Team A' AND Season = 2015 
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(RoundNo, ',', Season) AS Game, 'Opponent', OTotal 
FROM MatchDetails  
WHERE Team = 'Team A' AND Season = 2015;
```

The difference is the quotes around `Opponent`.

Comment: Yes!!  - cant believe it was so easy.